# AFHTTPRequestOperation Cancel Request

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

Is there a way to cancel a AFHTTPRequestOperation? I am using it to download a PLIST for example. So I was planning to have a button to cancel the download or task.
Is there a way?

Update:

```
operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFPropertyListResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id propertyList) {

    NSLog(@"DONE");        

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"%@", error);

}
 ];

 [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

So I have put "operation" to "operationQueue" and can stop the operation with:

```
[operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

This is only one operation in the queue. Is there a way to stop operation explicit if there are more than one? I guess the following error in the console - is it normal if a queue gets cancelled?

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use:

```
[operation cancel];
```

This is an NSOperation method that's implemented by AFNetworking.

Comment: How can I call this from another (void) because operation is only known in this function where the connection is called.

Comment: You have a few options.  For example, you could save `operation` as a weak @property, or you could add it to an NSOperationQueue instead of calling `start` on it, and then find it later from the same queue.  Here's a good overview of NSOperation: http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/

Comment: Thanks for the hint with NSOperation. Have updated my code above. I think if a operation is canceled the error in the console log is normal?

Comment: Yes, the error -999 is expected behavior.  If you eventually have more than one operation, you can look in the `operationQueue.operations` array, and search for the one you want.  For example, you could look at `operation.request.URL.path` to see if it contains the URL you are trying to cancel.

Comment: @AaronBrager Is there any way to get rid of the errors in the console?

Comment: @Ruddy Don't log the error if `error.code == kCFURLErrorCancelled && [error.domain isEqualToString:NSURLErrorDomain]`

Comment: @AaronBrager Ah I forgot to say this is being logged by AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger. Thought you may have some experience with it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Ruddy Set a [filter predicate](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger/1.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger.html#//api/name/filterPredicate).

Comment: @AaronBrager Not sure how I missed that, cheers. And just to clarify this, the errors are fine? They will not cause problems or anything like that?

Comment: @Ruddy `kCFURLErrorCancelled` is typically safe to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to cancel all operations:

```
[[httpClient operationQueue] cancelAllOperations];
```

Comment: What exactly is httpClient? For me it is an undeclared identifier. Thanks

Comment: `httpClient` is the instance of `AFHTTPClient` you used to create the connection. Anyway, I just realized that Aaron's answer works better for you case.