# Downloading concurrent song files

Tags: ios

I am Very new to iOS Application Development Platform,  I am searching for one thing from Last Few weeks, actually my requirement is I have a `UITableview` with few Urls,and On `didselectRowAtIndexPath` That song should run in the Background and it downloading progress shows in another tab.

When I clicked multiple Buttons then multiple songs are downloaded simultaneously and all downloading progress should shown individually in the next Tab and here I have felicity to Pause, resume, and cancel the particular download. this is my requirement. I use AFNetworking But it is not Clear Please Help me and do the needful.
my AFNetworking code below

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:downLoadedUrlParam];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:3600];

NSString *MUSICFile=[DocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:songName];
self.operation = [[AFDownloadRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request targetPath:MUSICFile shouldResume:YES];

[self.operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", MUSICFile);
    //[ProcessingUrlsArray removeObject:videoString];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    if(operation.response.statusCode!= 200) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Error While Downloaded" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}];

[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:self.operation];

[self.operation setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpected, long long totalBytesReadForFile, long long totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile) {
    float percentDone = totalBytesReadForFile/(float)totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile;
    NSLog(@"------%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CUR : %lli M",totalBytesReadForFile/1024/1024]);
    NSLog(@"------%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TOTAL : %lli M",totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile/1024/1024]);

    NSLog(@"------%f",percentDone);
    NSLog(@"------%.0f%%",percentDone*100);

    self.myProgressBar.progress=percentDone;

    NSLog(@"Operation%i: bytesRead: %d", 1, bytesRead);
    NSLog(@"Operation%i: totalBytesRead: %lld", 1, totalBytesRead);
    NSLog(@"Operation%i: totalBytesExpected: %lld", 1, totalBytesExpected);
    NSLog(@"Operation%i: totalBytesReadForFile: %lld", 1, totalBytesReadForFile);
    NSLog(@"Operation%i: totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile: %lld", 1, totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile);


    NSLog(@"%@",downLoadedUrlParam);
    self.title=downLoadNameParam;
    NSMutableArray *stgPerst;
    stgPerst=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
    NSDictionary *dicInfo=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",percentDone],downLoadNameParam] forKeys:@[@"heProg",@"heName"]];



    NSLog(@"dict=%@",dicInfo);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS" object:nil userInfo:dicInfo];

}];
```

Comment: You can refere to this thread for the similar problem.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638611/afhttprequestoperation-cancel-request

Comment: There is no even clue in that URl

Comment: Check this comment by Aaron Brager-  "If you eventually have more than one operation, you can look in the operationQueue.operations array, and search for the one you want. For example, you could look at operation.request.URL.path to see if it contains the URL you are trying to cancel."

Comment: OK thankyou, But could you explain in detail, actually I am New to this platform